# Capacitive Trimmer - Why is it full of silicone glue?

Tags: capacitor, circuit-design, resonance

I bought two of these trimmers from Digikey to tune a resonant circuit, but the screw is covered with silicone. I dug out the silicone with an xacto so I could turn the screw. Why is the silicone there? Seems counter-productive.

[image]

Comment: Do you think you could get an in-focus photo and crop it? 98% of your photo is useless background.

Comment: I suspect it's sealant to prevent contamination during solder reflow and flux washing operations.

Comment: @BSEE - Don't you mean "silicone", not "silicon"? Silicon is what circuit components are made of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many trim caps cannot be cleaned. Murata, for example, recommends against cleaning for many of their products:

[image]

but they do have some (eg. **TZB4 Series**) with a 'cover film'.

[image]

Recommended procedure after mounting and cleaning:

[image]

In Digikey's photo you can see what looks like silicone (rather than the typical polyimide cover film one would expect from the name).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Silicone is good for heat and water resistance such as Thermal Reflow Oven and Aqua solder flux cleaning making it suitable for a variety of assembly processes.
It also stabilizes the position from vibration.

I suspect it should be left in.

I haven't tried but isn't this just an outside layer sealant that can be operated with the trimmer tool?  Does it affect pF readings?

[image]